# Why can't I successfully send the array via the POST method in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, http-post

I'm new here and I'm learning Express, although I think I'm on the right track, I'm currently having some problems with the `POST` method. What happens to me now is the following:

- When I send a `POST` request to an http file, I receive an empty object `{}`. Also, I have done tests through Thunder client but, I receive a 400 error or another http error,
- Doesn't work `Content-Type: application/json` below path in method in http file,
- `GET` method works fine,
- This is the code I've been working with:

```js
const express = require('express');
const { stories } = require('../data/books.js').infoBooks;

const routerStories = express.Router();
routerStories.use(express.json());

routerStories.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const newBook = req.body;
    stories.push(newBook);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(stories));  
});
```

I've been trying to solve it for several days. And though, I've done quite a bit to research, I haven't been able to figure it out.
Please, I'd greatly appreciate your perspective and experience to be able to finish resolving this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few things wrong here with your code. Im going to assume you pasted the code as is so here is what you need to change.

1.) I don't think this line here is valid javascript or if it is its a bit strange. `const { stories } = require('../data/books.js').infoBooks;` if `infoBooks` is an object that contains stories just import the object

2.) you shouldn't need to set the router as json as the method exists on the router by default and will accept json as a valid response

3.) its possible you are not using a different route name and another route is using the same string literal.

You have not provided enough information so there could be another issue with how you are using the router itself but from what you have posted these are all the issues I have identified. hope it helps!

```
import {infoBooks} from "../data/books.js"
import express from "express";
const router = express.Router();

routerStories.post('/createNewBook', (req, res) => {
    const newBook = req.body;
    if(!newBook){
       res.status(400).json({message: "invalid arguments"})
       return
    }
    infoBooks.stories.push(newBook);
    //we don't need to set status here because by default the response will be 200
    res.json({infoBooks.stories});
    return 
})
```

Comment: Hi JSON Derulo,
• I’m using "const { stories } = require('../data/books.js').infoBooks;" to tell it to express where is the body structure that I need to extract to run the POST request and where is the database. Also, without that, the GET method didn’t work (well, whomever I learned this structure from, it worked perfectly). 
• Within the database I have different genders and, in the same way, I have routers in the Routers file.
• Anyway, I’m going to try the code you give me. I’ll be updating you with progress.
Thank you very much.

PDT. Quite a name: “JSON Derulo”, Nice!

Comment: then you should be exporting it like this 
``` 
export const infoBooks = {stories: []}
//or
export {
infoBooks
}
```

Comment: Hi @JSON Derulo, The test with the code you gave me had a negative result. This is the output the terminal shows me: " [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting... "